# Alpine docker image __isnan: symbol not found

Tags: docker, go, alpine-linux, libc

Here's the Dockerfile I am using to build a Golang application and a worker

```
FROM golang:1.15 AS build

RUN mkdir -p /go/api/proj

WORKDIR /go/api/proj

COPY go.* ./

RUN go mod download

COPY . .

RUN go mod tidy

RUN go build -o proj ./api/

RUN go build -o worker ./worker/

FROM alpine:3.14

WORKDIR /

RUN apk add libc6-compat cmake

RUN ln -s /lib/libc.musl-x86_64.so.1 /lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2

COPY . .

COPY --from=build /go/api/proj/proj .

COPY --from=build /go/api/proj/worker .

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["./worker"]
```

I had to add libc6-compat because kafka setup in worker wasn't compatible with musl library of alpine

Here's the error I received when trying to run worker in docker container

```
Error relocating ./worker: __strdup: symbol not found
Error relocating ./worker: __isnan: symbol not found
Error relocating ./worker: __strndup: symbol not found
```

Can someone suggest what's going wrong here and solution for it?

I am using confluent kafka in worker which may be the reason for this error.

Comment: Alpine has a modified system C library that can lead to incompatibilities like this.  Can you use a `debian` or `ubuntu` image as the base for the final stage, or use an Alpine-based builder stage?

Comment: My goal is to have the final build size under 100 MB. with this docker file, it is coming around ~80 MB. If I move to Debian based image, it comes around 200 MB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can someone suggest what's going wrong here and solution for it?

What you are doing here:

> `RUN ln -s /lib/libc.musl-x86_64.so.1 /lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`

is *pretending* that Musl is GLIBC. It isn't, and that doesn't work.

From [Musl FAQ](https://www.musl-libc.org/faq.html):

> Binary compatibility is much more limited, but it will steadily increase with new versions of musl. At present, some glibc-linked shared libraries can be loaded with musl, but all but the simplest glibc-linked applications will fail if musl is dropped-in in place of `/lib/ld-linux.so.2`.

Instead of building the `worker` binary against GLIBC and then trying to run it with Musl, you should build it against Musl.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment. Initially I tried using musl only, but it failed due to some librdkafka issue.
But after reading your comment, I decided to give it a try and it WORKED by adding these libraries: make gcc libtool musl-dev